# i need help getting stDev without using importmath, python

Tags: python, function, unpack

```
### import math

def mean(values):
    return sum(values)*1.0/len(values)

    def std():
        pass
    print(std())

    def std(values):
            length = len(values)
        if length < 2:
            return("Standard deviation requires at least two data points")
        m = mean(values)
        total_sum = 0
        for i in range(length):
            total_sum += (values[i]-m)**2
        under_root = total_sum*1.0/length
        return math.sqrt(under_root) 

    vals = [5]
    stan_dev = std(vals)
    print(stan_dev)

    values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    stan_dev = std(values)

    print(stan_dev)

__________________________________________________________________________


lst = [3, 19, 21, 1435, 653342]

sum = reduce((lambda x, y: x +y), lst)
print (sum) 

# list = [3, 19, 21, 1435, 653342]
```

i need to be able to get the stDev without using sum or len
i need to 'unpack' the stDev ???

Comment: can you add some more details as to what exactly you are trying to achieve, desired output etc plus correct the code format in your question?

Comment: To compute a standard deviation you need to extract a square root. In Python the `sqrt` function lives in the `math` module. If you insist on doing this without importing `math` then you are going to have to write your own square root function. That is a bit of a tall order when all you really want is the standard deviation.

Comment: You can get a square root with a power of 1/2 (and thus without the math import).

Comment: I can use square root from math just need to get sum and Length without using Len to get the mean and then st dev

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two loops (there are shorter ways but this is simple):

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# Calculate the mean first
N, X = 0, 0
for xi in arr:
    N += 1
    X += xi
mean = X/N

# Calculate the standard deviation
DSS = 0
for xi in arr:
    DSS += (xi - mean)**2
std = (DSS/N)**(1/2)
```

Outputs `4.5` for `mean` and `2.872` for `std`.

Comment: for a list of [1,2,3,4,5] the std is supposed to be 1.58  when i plug those numbers into this formula i get .89   the mean comes out right at 3

Comment: The standard deviation for the array [1,2,3,4,5] is 1.4142 (I checked with numpy) and this is what the code above correctly outputs. This could be down to your required standard deviation formula (that divides by N-1 instead of N) in which case the std formula should be `std = (DSS/(N-1))**(1/2)`. [Here is a sandbox with the code running - proving it gives the correct answer](https://edube.org/sandbox/2c66b1e2-6a2e-11e9-948f-0242e71d5f55).